# Facing issues while trying to use Sqlite in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone app, i have added the reference of `Sqlite For Windows Phone` but when i try to add it in my `MainPage.xaml.cs` with `using Sqlite` it shows *`Type or namespace could not be found!`*. Anyone knows how to fix it out?

[image: Sample image of references]

Answer (score 0):

`using Sqilte` looks like a typo.  Could that be your problem?

Comment: VS highlights it when I try to include it ...@fooser

Comment: Namespaces and Types are case sensitive also, so if Sqlite isn't working for you, try using SQLite.

Comment: I'm not that much lazy, have done earlier but no difference ! @fooser